# How do you convert filters back into an RGB value?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I'm going through a tutorial on convolutional neural networks and am getting stuck on the first step. When I ran `plt.imshow(output[0])` I was told that the dimensions are wrong. I know that the last list size must be 3 or 0 for imshow to work but currently, it is 64 due to the number of filters.

I tried setting the number of filters to 3 which surprisingly worked, but I don't think that is what I am supposed to be doing...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn.datasets as skd


image = skd.load_sample_image("china.jpg")
input_layer = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 427, 640, 3])
conv_1 = tf.layers.conv2d(input_layer, filters=64, kernel_size=[3, 3],padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    output = sess.run(conv_1, feed_dict={input_layer: [image]})
plt.imshow(output[0])
plt.show()
```

Comment: The last dimension of output of conv operation is the number of filters, so with 3 filters it will work to no surprise. What exactly are you trying to do? Visualize convolution filters?

Comment: I apologize, I'm very new to Tensorflow. I guess my question boils down to what does the number of filters represent? I think I'm trying to do what you said, "visualize convolution filters". Like if there are 64 values at each pixel in the image, what do those values represent?

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444120/understanding-the-output-shape-of-conv2d-layer-in-keras/55444554#55444554
http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/
http://cs231n.github.io/understanding-cnn/

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I have some reading to do, but this seems very useful! @Sharky