# Performing 2D convolution on 4D data in Keras

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have data of dimension `24*64*64*10` (excluding the batch size).

I want to split the input into 24 inputs of dimension `64*64*10`, perform `Conv2D` on each of them and then concatenate them to get the 4D data again for further processing.

Any help regarding the implementation would be helpful. I am working with Keras.

Edit: I tried to the following code to perform the 2D convolution

```
num_ch= 24
input= Input(shape=(64,64,10,num_ch))
print(input.shape)
branch_out= []
for i in range(num_ch):
    out= Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,:,:,i] )(input)
    print(out.shape)
    out= Conv2D(10, kernel_size=(3,3),strides= (1,1), padding='same', data_format= 'channels_last')(input)
    branch_out.append(out)
```

I got the following error:

```
(?, 64, 64, 10, 24)
(?, 64, 64, 10)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-51977f4edbba> in <module>
      7     out= Lambda(lambda x: x[:,:,:,:,i] )(input)
      8     print(out.shape)
----> 9     out= Conv2D(10, kernel_size=(3,3),strides= (1,1), padding='same', data_format= 'channels_last')(input)
     10     branch_out.append(out)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    412                 # Raise exceptions in case the input is not compatible
    413                 # with the input_spec specified in the layer constructor.
--> 414                 self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
    415 
    416                 # Collect input shapes to build layer.

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
    309                                      self.name + ': expected ndim=' +
    310                                      str(spec.ndim) + ', found ndim=' +
--> 311                                      str(K.ndim(x)))
    312             if spec.max_ndim is not None:
    313                 ndim = K.ndim(x)

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_25: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5
```

I don't understand why it is still showing the dimentionalilty as 5.

Comment: Your previous and exactly the same question was closed as Too Broad, you should not post the exact same question again, you should try to improve so people can answer it, which will produce a different question.

Comment: Change     `out= Conv2D(10, kernel_size=(3,3),strides= (1,1), padding='same', data_format= 'channels_last')(input)`
 to     `out= Conv2D(10, kernel_size=(3,3),strides= (1,1), padding='same', data_format= 'channels_last')(out)`. The input to Conv2D should be `out` not `input`

Answer (score 0):

The output format of a 2D convolution is 4D tensor of the form

> (batch_size, height, width, channels) (with data_format="channel_last" by default).

So if a 32x32x3 image input is given to a conv2D layer with number of filters = 8 and kernel size = (1X1) (a 2D conv layer will have a 2D kernal matrix), the output tensor will be (none, 32, 32, 8)
To know how a 2d kernel works on a 3D image refer [Understanding the output shape of conv2d layer in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444120/understanding-the-output-shape-of-conv2d-layer-in-keras)

For your code, simply replace input by (64,64,10)

```
input= Input(shape=(64,64,10))
out= Conv2D(10, kernel_size=(3,3),strides= (1,1), padding='same', data_format= 'channels_last')(input)
```